# Issue regarding getting dividend yield in google sheets from google finance

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance

I am having an issue with getting dividend yield from google finance in google sheets.

I am using this formula
=GOOGLEFINANCE("MSFT","yieldpct")

,but this returns a error "Formula parse error"

Am I missing something here ? Is there a need for additional parameters ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [googlefinance()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en) documentation states that this particular attribute `yieldpct` is reserved for `mutual funds` and **not** `stock tickers`

[image]

---

its working good with `mutual funds` tickers

[image]